# Not able to read data from external properties file in java Eclipse, Even property file is loaded but getting null

Tags: java, null, properties-file

I am not able to read data from an external properties file in Java Eclipse, when the properties file is loaded but I keep getting `null`. I've created the properties file externally in notepad.

```java
 Properties objpro = new Properties();    
 objpro.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\Auto_WorkSpace\\CN_First_Testing_Project\\src\\Test_Component.properties"));    
 System.out.println(objpro.getProperty("Email"));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Test_Component.properties

Balli.class=JI    
Email=CNmailID    
Password=Passcode

Comment: What is null exactly ?

Comment: I guess Value in return

Comment: Are you sure there's a property "Email"? Check for typos...

Comment: Yes it has.. see first comment...

Comment: Dont put more infos into comments; edit your question instead. And are you sure that this file path is 100% correct?

Comment: Yes.. file path is correct.. but I've created properties file externally with notepad.... another properties file which i've created in Eclipse it self is working.. ... why external file is not working-? :(

Comment: looks like issue is with your property file..have each property in a separate line

Comment: @Pro : Yes i do have each property in separate line

Comment: either issue with property file or issue with the path - otherwise code should work, its absolutely fine..

Comment: Yes.. i said code is working.. issue is with property file .. which i've created manually... but i have to read value from manual file...

Comment: Share your property file. I test it on my system it is working fine.

Comment: Issue Solved... I've created notepad file as a Unicode file.. now i've changed it to ASCII file and it's working now....